# Losing data when converting from vector to raster of 1 sqkm resolution?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, raster-conversion

I am dealing with 1000 species data over the region of my interest. when I convert my this 1000 species polygon into raster by 1km by 1km resolution in QGIS. All data is in one polygon. The resultant tiff file contains only 15 species data. SO much data is gone? what is the reason?

Setting
Figure 1
I have this attribute table and contain 232 species shown by highlight region.
[image]

Figure 2
setting for conversion.
[image]

Comment: Show the setting you use when converting it

Comment: Please have a look on again_BERA

Comment: You are using `fid` as burn in value so the output raster is going to have only the fid as value. Why do you want to convert the polygons to raster? It doesnt seem suitable if you want to keep all polygon attributes. Maybe create a square grid instead and spatial join your polygon data to the grid

Comment: Is it possible that your output extent values are a subset of the input polygon area?  If so, that would have the effect of clipping the input to a smaller output area, and thereby reducing the number of input species.

Comment: -BERA I have made square grid and clip it for my raster area how can I join this with my polygon? like merge two layers one polygon and other this grid one?

Comment: -Stu Smith what does that mean of "Is it possible that your output extent values are a subset of the input polygon area?".

Comment: If any of your species polygons overlap, you will only get the value of the last polygon to be rasterized at that pixel, as every subsequent polygon overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Is it any way to get rid of this problem and get data of species in each cell by cell. -user2856